# Unity3d UI Masking Prefab Issue

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, layer

Hello iv'e ran into a bit of trouble with the Unity3d UI Masking. So basicly in this picture below you could obiously see that the prefabs are in front of the UI. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? If so let me know thanks:

[image: Menu screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, check the Canvas ( for your UI elements ) Render Mode is 'Screen Space - overlay'

Comment: yeah but when i set it as that for some reason in the Game Scene the UI Is gone.

Comment: Oh never mind I just opened a new scene and remade the canvas turns out my canvas was just sloppy and then added Canvas Scaler Component and screen space - overlay like you said. Thanks :)